# SQL - create new col based on value of other column group by third column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table

| Id | item | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | itemA1 | X |
| A | itemA2 | X |
| B | itemA1 | X |
| B | itemA2 | X |
| B | itemA3 | Y |

And i would like to create new indicator which contains the information about if the Id contains only item of type X or only tpye Y or both like this :

| Id | Indicator |
| --- | --- |
| A | Only X |
| B | Both |

EDIT: It's possible to have more than 2 kind of types

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sorry for that, i accepted your answer and this, i did not know that is not possible to accept several answers. But anyway, this response is the best that i expected because it return for an Id, all the possible types :)

Comment: Hi, i mention this in another comment :) 
It's a toy example in my question. But in the future i will be careful to specify all possible cases

Comment: In addition, why Mikhail answered correctly at my question if i did'nt mention what i want in my question ?? :)

Comment: i undertsand your frustration and i would like to thanks to you for your time to have spend to respond to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below generic approach

```
select id, 
  if(count(distinct type)=1,'Only ','') || string_agg(distinct type) indicator
from your_table
group by id
```

Answer (score -1):

This will cover if both item are 'Y' as well:

```
with table_with_sample_data as (
select 'A'  as Id ,'itemA1' as item,  'X' as type union all
select  'A',  'itemA2',   'X' union all
select  'B',  'itemA1', 'X' union all
select  'B',  'itemA2', 'X' union all
select  'B',  'itemA3', 'Y' union all
select  'C', 'itemA1',  'Y' union all
select  'C', 'itemA2',  'Y'
)

select id, 
  if(count(distinct type)=1,'Only '|| max(type), 'Both')  indicator from table_with_sample_data
group by id
```

Comment: And, how to specify in "both" case what are the types if i have multiple other types possible ?